# Non-equivalent norms on finite dimensional vector spaces over a non-complete field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

It is widely known that on a finite-dimensional vector space over a complete field, every norm is equivalent. However, I'm trying (and failing) to find a counterexample over a field which is not complete.

My first try was to treat $\mathbb{Q}$ as a vector space over itself and find two non-equivalent norms. As for Ostrowski's theorem we know that, for example, the absolute value and the 2-adic norm are not equivalent. However, I noticed that the $p$-adic norm, though being a norm on the field $\mathbb{Q}$, it is not a norm on the vector space $(\mathbb{Q},|\cdot |)$.

I have tried to find such norms in $\mathbb{Q}^2$ and other (not complete) fields to no avail. I'm content with any example, but it would be great if it's accompanied by the proof of their non-equivalence.

Comment: Maybe it is more helpful if you regard an easier field like $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for $p \in \mathbb{P}$ then you can choose an adequate topology.

Comment: Try taking $V=\Bbb Q[x]/(f)$, where $f$ is an irreducible polynomial where one root $\alpha$ of $f$ is in $\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R$ and one root $\beta$ is in $\Bbb R$. Then $\Bbb Q[x]/(f)\cong\Bbb Q(\alpha)\cong\Bbb Q(\beta)$ as fields and therefore as $\Bbb Q$-vector spaces (even $(\Bbb Q,\left|\cdot\right|)$-vector spaces), but if the topologies are different (e.g. the one on $\Bbb Q(\beta)$ is the order topology, and the one on $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ cannot be ordered), the norms cannot be equivalent.

Comment: Do you require that the norms take only values in the same field that the vector space is over? I thought of a $2$-dimensional example with a vector space over the field  $\mathbb Q$ but one of my norms takes real values that are not all in $\mathbb Q.$

Comment: I'm defining a norm as a real-valued function so that's not a problem :)

Comment: This has been crossposted at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265192/non-equivalent-norms-on-finite-dimensional-vector-spaces-over-a-non-complete-fie) and has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered in the comment section, which [should not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756) be used for giving answers. Let me summarize the comments then.

1. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265192 gives examples of norms on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ which are not equivalent.
2. If $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial which has a root $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$  and a root $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle f \rangle$ can be given two non-equivalent norms.

Comment: For example, a duplicate of this question was [just posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841065). But it cannot be marked as a duplicate of this one since this question here has no (upvoted) answer.

Comment: Upvored, so you can now mark it correctly.